# Why doesn't this simple Object.create example work?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, prototypal-inheritance

The below code is saying object has no method hehe

```
var A = function () {
                this.hehe = function () { };
            };
var B = function () {};
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype, {
                constructor: {
                    value: B,
                    enumerable: false,
                    writable: true,
                    configurable: true
                }
            });
var _b = new B();
    _b.hehe();
```

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/

Comment: If you want to know more about constructor functions and prototype maybe this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want B to have access to that function you need to define it in the prototype of A.

```
A.protototype.hehe = function(){
 //do something
};
```

Your call to the parents constructor is also missing in b.

With this.hehe every instance of A is getting it's own hehe function, thus not being in the prototype.

Also a nicer implentation of prototypal inhertiance is as follows - Well that is a matter of opinion I know.

```
function __extends(child,parent){ //Global function for inheriting from objects

    function Temp(){this.constructor = child;} //Create a temporary ctor
    Temp.prototype = parent.prototype; 
    child.prototype = new Temp(); //Set the child to an object with the child's ctor    with the parents prototype
}

var B = (function(_parent){
__extends(B,A);

function B(){

 _parent.call(this);
 }

})(A);
```

Comment: Thanks guys, just "clicked" with prototypical inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing an instance of A as the prototype, not A's prototype.

i.e. you should call your create call should look like `Object.create(new A(), ...`

Comment: No, you should pass the object which should be the prototype of the newly-created object.

Comment: Sorry, now I know what you meant.

Comment: If hehe can be set directly on the prototype than @Fendorio's answer is great. But if hehe needs to be inside of A (for example if it is a closure) then either  a new A needs to be created, or A() needs to be called inside of B on B's this (as in SLaks answer). In the latter case a new hehe will be defined for each B, which may not be desirable. Although my answer may be the best in all situations, it may be apropriate in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

`hehe()` is not a member of `A.prototype`; it's a property of each `A` instance assigned in its constructor.

Since you never call the `A` constructor, `_b` doesn't have it.

You need to call your base constructor in the derived constructor:

```
A.call(this);
```